# How to write junit of init()?

Tags: java, servlets, junit

Hi I am a beginner in junit's and I got stumbled upon the junit of init() method which I defined in my servlet.

Here is my servlet.

```
  public class EmailSendingServlet extends HttpServlet{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7796409155466523414L;

        /**
         * Creates an Email Model Object
         */
        Email emailMessage = new Email();

        /**
         * Overrides the init constructor of servlet
         * 
         */
        public void init() {
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            emailMessage.setHostName(context.getInitParameter("host"));
            emailMessage.setPortName(context.getInitParameter("port")); 
        }
        /**
         * Overrides the Service method of Generic Servlet 
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            emailMessage.setFrom(request.getParameter("from"));
            emailMessage.setRecipient(request.getParameterValues("recipients"));
            emailMessage.setSubject(request.getParameter("subject"));
            emailMessage.setBody(request.getParameter("body"));
            emailMessage.setFile(request.getParameterValues("file"));

            String resultMessage = "";

            try {
                EmailUtility.sendEmail(emailMessage);
                resultMessage = "The Email was sent successfully";
                request.setAttribute("message", resultMessage);
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and given below is the test case of my servlet class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

    public class EmailSendingServletTest extends Mockito
    {

        @Test
        public void TestEmailSendingServlet() {

            HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
            HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = mock(RequestDispatcher.class);

            when(request.getParameter("from")).thenReturn("robi@robi.com");
            String[] recipients = new String [3];
            recipients[0] = "abc@abc.com";
            recipients[1] = "xyz@xyz.com";
            recipients[2] = "qwe@qwe.com";
            when(request.getParameterValues("recipients")).thenReturn(recipients);
            when(request.getParameter("subject")).thenReturn("Test Mail");
            when(request.getParameter("body")).thenReturn("This is Body");
            String[] files = new String[1];
            files[0] = "C:\\Users\\asara3\\Documents\\Architecture.jpg";
            when(request.getParameterValues("file")).thenReturn(files);
            when(request.getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp")).thenReturn(requestDispatcher);

            try {
                new EmailSendingServlet().doPost(request, response);
            } catch (ServletException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

I am bit confused to stub the context.getInitParameter("host") in my test case ? Any help guys ?

Comment: Note: don't catch the exception in your test case. This test will currently pass if an exception is thrown. Add `throws` to the test method signature.

Comment: There shouldn't be any init() method. The emailMessage variable should be a local variable of doPost(). Remember that the same unique instance of your servlet handles all the requests to that servlet concurrently. You don't want two requests to write to the same EmailMessage object.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the suggestion. Will take care of that .

Comment: @JBNizet . Thanks for the suggestion. I thought of this way that when the servlet is going to initialise, the container takes all the parameters in DD (irrespective of either it is in config or context) and gives to the init(). So, I included the init() method just to be sure that the correct smtp settings goes into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `spy()` method of Mockito to mock the behavior of the `getServletContext()` method.

For example add this in your `setup()` method or in the constructor of the unit test class :

```
public class EmailSendingServletTest {
  ...
  private EmailSendingServlet emailSendingServlet;
  private EmailSendingServlet emailSendingServletSpy;
  ...

  public EmailSendingServletTest(){
    emailSendingServlet =  new EmailSendingServlet();
    emailSendingServletSpy = Mockito.spy(emailSendingServlet);
  }
}
```

Then you may mock the getServletContext() method like that :

```
Mockito.doReturn(yourMockedServletContext).when(emailSendingServletSpy.getServletContext());
```

Generally I avoid spying (that mocks the object under test) but in the case of third-party dependency as servlet, it is an acceptable case as refactoring is not able or else it forces us to write no standard changes in the way the third-party dependency is used. Which is often undesirable too.

Comment: Hi david, Thanks for the suggestion . What exactly do I need to spy ? What is this mail service ? I am getting confused.

Comment: Hello, you are welcome. Sorry typo. I updated. You have to spy `emailSendingServlet`, the object under test as explained :)

Comment: So did I tried. It's not working. Throwing Unfinished stubbing exception when I am trying to mock getServletContext() : 

private EmailSendingServlet servlet;
 
 @Test
 public void TestEmailSendingServlet() {

   servlet = new EmailSendingServlet();
   servlet = Mockito.spy(servlet);
   ServletContext context = mock(ServletContext.class);
   Mockito.doReturn(context).when(servlet.getServletContext());
   when(context.getInitParameter("host")).thenReturn("localhost");
   when(context.getInitParameter("port")).thenReturn("25");

Comment: Try by using another variable for the spy object. I updated. And why do you use PowerMock ? Do you really need it ??? It doesn't seem. If  you don't need it remove it as it may create side effect.